# Code Security in .Net

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I wrote a program and sent the compiled file to my friend. but after an hour, he sent me the code of that! How did he do that. And how can i prevent it?
is this problem just in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/). If you want make it difficult for people to understand the code, you have to ofuscate it (there are tools to do dat, like [dotfuscator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms227240%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

I don't know if it's a .NET only problem...

Answer (score 0):

Use an obfuscation tool like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator.

Answer (score 0):

ILSpy (http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) will show you the IL and can transform it to c#. You can try obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a design feature of .NET.  Read the following for a better understanding.

[Thwart Reverse Engineering of Your Visual Basic .NET or C# Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164058.aspx)